# Check Photo privacy for a user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My project is a Facebook application developed in asp.net MVC3. I want to check the privacy of a Facebook photo for a particular user.

I have Facebook userid and Facebook photo path. How can I check whether this user had permission to view this photo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this issue. By using fql we can query all the privacy details of an object from table "privacy":

```
SELECT value, description FROM privacy WHERE id = 10150146071791729.
```

From here we can get privacy details of an fb object; please see [this documentation reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/privacy/).

But the one issue still exist is that I am unable to check the privacy of a fb photo whose owner is not my friend. I am still searching for that.

Answer (score 1):

Found Graph API solution for getting privacy settings, but it's providing privacy settings of albums not for particular photos.

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,albums.fields(privacy)&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN